# how to use ICLRStrongName in .NET 4?

Tags: .net-4.0, assemblies, unmanaged

Related to my previous posts I'm moving to .NET 4. I've found that using the previous StrongName.h to get my assembly signing key in unmanaged code is now deprecated, and I need to use MetaHost.h and ICLRStrongName::StrongNameTokenFromAssembly.

The previous StrongNameTokenFromAssembly(..) was very straight forward, now this new one has no documentation on how to use. Does anyone have experience with this interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow... that required a lot of hacking around.  Here we go!

```
ICLRMetaHost *pMetaHost = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost,
               IID_ICLRMetaHost, (LPVOID*)&pMetaHost);  
if(hr == S_OK)
{
  WCHAR version[100];
  DWORD size;

  hr == pMetaHost->GetVersionFromFile(MyGetApplicationExecutablePath().c_str(), (LPWSTR) &version, &size);
  if(hr == S_OK)
  {
     LPWSTR assemblyVer = version;
     ICLRRuntimeInfo *pRuntimInfo = NULL;

     hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime(assemblyVer, IID_ICLRRuntimeInfo, (LPVOID*)&pRuntimInfo);
     if (hr == S_OK)
     {
        ICLRStrongName *pStrongName = NULL;
        hr = pRuntimInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRStrongName, IID_ICLRStrongName, (LPVOID*)&pStrongName);

        if(hr == S_OK)
        {
           pStrongName->StrongNameTokenFromAssembly(MyGetApplicationExecutablePath().c_str(), &token, &len);
           DWORD verified = 0;
           BOOLEAN sigVerified = pStrongName->StrongNameSignatureVerification(MyGetApplicationExecutablePath().c_str(), SN_INFLAG_FORCE_VER  , &verified);
           if (!verified)
           {
              //Do something nasty here if the Signature verification failed
           }
           pStrongName->StrongNameFreeBuffer(token);
        }
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: Greetings from 12 years in the future! This proved to be a great reference for me today.

Just wanted to mention a few fixes:
- The line with GetVersionFromFile should have a single '=', not '=='
- The line with StrongNameTokenFromAssembly references some variables that don't exist in the sample code. For me, I removed those lines as I only needed StrongNameSignatureVerification (which I changed to StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx)